# emqx start command is not starting the mqtt broker

Tags: linux-kernel, erlang, mqtt, erlang-shell, erlang-ports

I am having an issue with running emqx.
When I run emqx start, It shows:

```
emqx v3.2.7 is started successfully!
```

When I run emx_ctl status:

```
Node 'emqx@127.0.0.1' not responding to pings.
```

When I run emqx console:

```
MacBook-Pro:bin apple$ emqx console
!!!!
!!!! WARNING: ulimit -n is 256; 1024 is the recommended minimum.
!!!!
Exec: /usr/local/Cellar/emqx/3.2.7/erts-10.3.5/bin/erlexec -boot /usr/local/Cellar/emqx/3.2.7/releases/v3.2.7/emqx -mode embedded -boot_var ERTS_LIB_DIR /usr/local/Cellar/emqx/3.2.7/erts-10.3.5/../lib -mnesia dir "/usr/local/Cellar/emqx/3.2.7/data/mnesia/emqx@127.0.0.1" -config /usr/local/Cellar/emqx/3.2.7/data/configs/app.2019.12.13.02.35.23.config -args_file /usr/local/Cellar/emqx/3.2.7/data/configs/vm.2019.12.13.02.35.23.args -vm_args /usr/local/Cellar/emqx/3.2.7/data/configs/vm.2019.12.13.02.35.23.args -- console
Root: /usr/local/Cellar/emqx/3.2.7
/usr/local/Cellar/emqx/3.2.7
Erlang/OTP 21 [erts-10.3.5] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:32] [hipe] [dtrace]

{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,kernel,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,kernel_safe_sup,{on_load_function_failed,crypto}}},{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}}"}
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,kernel,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,kernel_safe_sup,{on_load_function_failed,crypto}}},{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}})

Crash dump is being written to: log/crash.dump...done
```

Comment: Why have you tagged this as `linux-kernel` when the console implies you are running on a Mac?

Comment: Is this a duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37607902/on-load-function-failed-cberl-nif-erlang